# How to clear out white space on top of zsh/iterm

Tags: terminal, zsh, desktop-customization, iterm

Hi I have been bugged by this for a while. Everytime I open up a new terminal window, there's a huge white space on top that doesn't do anything, same thing with my VSCode where I set the terminal to be iterm:

[image]

How do I clear this out??